# split dataframe at each repeating point in a column

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe

```
df<-data.frame(var1=c(1:11),I_var1=c(11:21),
               var2=c(rep(c(0,0.1),each=5),0.1),var4=c(rep(c(0:4),2),4))

var1 I_var1 var2 var4
  1     11  0.0    0
  2     12  0.0    1
  3     13  0.0    2
  4     14  0.0    3
  5     15  0.0    4
  6     16  0.1    0
  7     17  0.1    1
  8     18  0.1    2
  9     19  0.1    3
 10     20  0.1    4
 11     21  0.1    4
```

I have to split at each repeating cell of a particular number i.e. where df$var4==4

I tried-

```
X <- split(df,cut(df$var4,4))
```

But this is giving wrong result. 
What i want is-
2 dataframes (or lists as split gives list) where var4 is between 0 and 4. The second one should have both rows with var4==4.

I do not want to use subset as original dataframe has >10Mil records.

How do I do this and very fast?

Comment: How it should look like?

Comment: 2 lists with all columns but var4 should be 0:4 as I want to cut at every time a 4 appears in var4 columns

Answer (score 3):

Simply:

```
split(df,duplicated(df$var4))

$`FALSE`
  var1 I_var1 var2 var4
1    1     11    0    0
2    2     12    0    1
3    3     13    0    2
4    4     14    0    3
5    5     15    0    4

$`TRUE`
   var1 I_var1 var2 var4
6     6     16  0.1    0
7     7     17  0.1    1
8     8     18  0.1    2
9     9     19  0.1    3
10   10     20  0.1    4
11   11     21  0.1    4
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

df<-data.frame(var1=c(1:11),I_var1=c(11:21),
               var2=c(rep(c(0,0.1),each=5),0.1),var4=c(rep(c(0:4),2),4))

cuts <- which(df$var4==0)
cuts <- c(cuts,nrow(df))
df <- as.data.table(df)
df[,nrow:=.I]
intervals <- list()
for(i in 1:(length(cuts)-1)){ # i <- 1
  intervals[[i]] <- seq(cuts[i],cuts[i+1]-1,1) 
}
intervals[[i]] <- c(intervals[[i]],max(intervals[[i]])+1)


list <- list()
for(i in 1:length(intervals)){ # i <- 1
  list[[i]] <- df[nrow%in%intervals[[i]],]
}
```

Gives as output

```
> list
[[1]]
   var1 I_var1 var2 var4 nrow
1:    1     11    0    0    1
2:    2     12    0    1    2
3:    3     13    0    2    3
4:    4     14    0    3    4
5:    5     15    0    4    5

[[2]]
   var1 I_var1 var2 var4 nrow
1:    6     16  0.1    0    6
2:    7     17  0.1    1    7
3:    8     18  0.1    2    8
4:    9     19  0.1    3    9
5:   10     20  0.1    4   10
6:   11     21  0.1    4   11
```

**UPDATE**

Or shorter

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

df<-data.frame(var1=c(1:11),I_var1=c(11:21),
               var2=c(rep(c(0,0.1),each=5),0.1),var4=c(rep(c(0:4),2),4))

cuts <- which(df$var4==0)
df <- as.data.table(df)
df[,nrow:=.I]
list <- list()
for(i in 1:length(cuts)){ # i <- 2
 if(i==length(cuts)){
   list[[i]] <- df[nrow%in%c(cuts[i]:nrow(df)),]
 }else{
   list[[i]] <- df[nrow%in%c(cuts[i]:(cuts[i+1]-1)),]
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Not sure, if I fully understood you ..)

```
df<-data.frame(var1=c(1:11),I_var1=c(11:21),
               var2=c(rep(c(0,0.1),each=5),0.1),var4=c(rep(c(0:4),2),4))

df$lagvar4<-c(0,df$var4[-length(df$var4)])
split(df[!(colnames(df) %in% c("var4","lagvar4"))],cumsum(df$lagvar4==4))
```

Comment: @P Lapointe Thanks!! I had no idea about this duplicate function! Really helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

```
df <- data.frame(var1=c(1:11),I_var1=c(11:21),
           var2=c(rep(c(0,0.1),each=5),0.1),var4=c(rep(c(0:4),2),4))

df %>% 
  group_by(var4) %>% 
  mutate(split = row_number()) %>% 
  split(., f = .$split)
```